# Django model fields get realigned after writing wrong data

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django admin panel, whenever I leave a field blank and save it the fields are realigned left to right and vice versa.
In the below pics 1st pic is when there is no data in the fields. 2nd pic is when i leave a field blank and save it the field has realigned from left to right.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to fix this?
![Before writing anything in my panel[![After leaving a field blank][1]][1]][2]

[![After leaving a field blank][1]][1]

Comment: Looks like a CSS spacing issue. There's an additional text (error message) below the "Jira subdomain" field which causes the "Api token" to slide left.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix this as if i leave api token empty the same thing happens with project id field and it moves right.